# Best way to implement traffic light/intersection in 2D tile-based traffic simulation

Tags: implementations, simulation

I've been building a traffic simulation with C++ following the Intelligent Driver Model from this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/simulating-traffic-flow-in-python-ee1eab4dd20f

To sum up my implementation:

- The map is divided into 2D grid of `Tile`(s)
- Each `Tile` has a list of `Road`(s). For the sake of simplicity, **no road will merge into another road/diverge from itself** (each road can only connect to others at their endpoints). If a road violates that, I would break it into two roads right at the merge/diverge point.
- Each `Road` has a list of `Node`(s). The update function will connect the dots, and I'll have my road.
- Traffic signals can only be placed at endpoints.

The article doesn't mention anything about when roads just intersect other roads (without traffic lights' guidance), so I develop my own system.

Before the simulation starts, every tile will find every intersection possible within its roads, store the positions and the information of the roads crossing that intersection into a separate `IntersectNode` (with no relation to `Node`), which is then thrown into a `IntersectManager`. In an update loop, the  manager loops through all the nodes, which goes through all the intersecting roads and control velocities of cars on those roads.

Problems arise when I go back to implementing traffic lights: I want to point at where I want lights to be, since the roads are fixed (Ex: At the beginning of road 1,3,5 of tile (1, 3) place a light). But traffic lights **are** `IntersectNode`(s), and now there seems to be no good way of separating the two (or to specify which are which).

1. Leaving both might lead to conflicts when controlling vehicles' velocity.
2. Differentiating by position might lead to floating point inaccuracies.
3. Differentiating by which road(s) cross the node might lead to duplications, since 2 or more road can cross each other multiple times (again, for simplicity, **no road cross over itself**).
4. Manually hardcoding which road intersect which, and which are also traffic lights can make things complicated exponentially.

So, what's the best way of implementing this? I'm not really looking for maximal efficiency, but rather ease of implementation, use and reuse.

Edit: shorter problem statememt: Within a tile, intersections are calculated automatically, while traffic lights are placed manually. So traffic lights always lay on top of intersections. Problem is, traffic lights and intersections have different effect on cars (as in real life). So I need to remove the intersection's effect when a traffic light is already there.

Edit 2: To be considered "connected", one road's endpoint must be another road's start point. "Crossing" is just when roads overlap each other (for example, when two roads form an "X" shape).

Comment: This seems to be a question about your input data and not about how to design the software? as I understand it, someone gave you ambiguous traffic light coordinates and you're asking how to fix them?

Comment: @user253751 yes, I will be providing the input data for the traffic light, but it's mainly about how to best add those lights without colliding with the previously built system, or should I just redesign it all together. I'm basically fixing my own mess.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, then. I also don't see how the tiles are in any way relevant.

Comment: you want to know whether cars queued at a traffic light should be treated the same as cars that are stopped in the middle of the intersection?

Comment: @user253751 no, I have already figure how cars should interact with those. Main point here, intersections are calculated automatically, while traffic lights are placed manually. So traffic lights always lay on top of an intersection. Problem is, traffic lights and intersections have different effect on cars. So I need to remove the intersection's effect when a traffic light is already there. But with how I had designed the intersections, things ain't that easy.

Comment: why not just check if a traffic light is there when adding the intersection?

Comment: @user253751 isn't it just all those problems i mentioned above, but in reverse?

Comment: so your problem is how to associate calculated intersection points with points specified in a file? just pick some reasonable distance tolerance like 1 centimeter

Comment: @user253751 wouldn't curved roads be bad then? Or if too many intersections in a small area? But I suppose I could just ignore those cases or something. I think.

Comment: then how about you specify the roads and the nodes the intersection is between

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145558/discussion-between-silverfox-and-user253751).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly you are just storing roads, generate a graph over this road network at runtime, but have issues with manually entered information like traffic lights that affect the behavior of these runtime generated intersections.

In this graph representation the edges would represent a road section without any changes. Any behavior, like yielding, stopping, speed change, etc should be represented by a node.

The solution seem rather clear to me. Use some form of editor to generate this graph over the road network and store the graph instead. This should allow you to make changes to the graph to add traffic lights, or anything else. The editor can still have convenient functions for detecting intersections when adding a new road, and update the graph accordingly.

Since this seem to be a highly visual problem I would highly recommend an visual editor that shows the actual roads. Trying to enter coordinates by hand in an xml/json file seem like it would be highly error prone, and not scale particularly well for more complex road networks.

Comment: Yes, I'm entering every coordinate by hand, which is a hassle. I've been considering building a editor after the simulation is finished, but seems like I'd have to do it now.